# How to put label with 8085 microprocessor in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, simulator, microprocessors, 8085

I have a code that should convert uppercase letters to lowercase using 8085 microprocessor (the GNUSim8085 simulator). However, the code is not readable, and immediately throws an error in row "lowercase:", that "the line of code must be given a label". Maybe you know how to give a label or fix this error, so, the code could convert uppercase to lowercase letters?

```
jmp lowercase 

lowercase:
    mov b, a ; move N (length of text) to register B
    mov c, h ; move high byte of HL to register C
    mov d, l ; move low byte of HL to register D

lowercase_loop:
    ldax d ; load character from memory address pointed to by HL into accumulator
    cpi 'A' ; compare character in accumulator with uppercase 'A'
    jc lowercase_skip ; if character is less than 'A', skip to next character
    cpi 'Z'+1 ; compare character in accumulator with one greater than uppercase 'Z'
    jnc lowercase_skip ; if character is not less than or equal to 'Z', skip to next character
    add a, 'a'-'A' ; convert uppercase character to lowercase
    stax d ; store character in accumulator back to memory address pointed to by HL

lowercase_skip:
    inx h ; increment high byte of HL
    inx d ; increment low byte of HL
    dec b ; decrement B (counter)
    jnz lowercase_loop ; repeat loop until B becomes zero
    ret ; return to caller

hlt
```

exact error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZsbu.png)

Comment: Is that the exact error message? That phrase turns up no search results. Please edit the question to include the actual error output.

Comment: I updated the description about the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From GNUSim8085's  docs, specifically the [Assembly Language Guide](https://github.com/GNUSim8085/GNUSim8085/blob/master/doc/asm-guide.txt):

> Labels must always be placed in the first column and must be followed by an instruction (no empty line).

This is an awkward restriction but it is documented.  So write:

```
lowercase: mov b, a ; move N (length of text) to register B
    mov c, h ; move high byte of HL to register C
    mov d, l ; move low byte of HL to register D
```

To make this look better, you might want to increase your indentation, or use shorter labels.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe do you know why the line with code  add a, 'a'-'A' is not working? How we could change that? The error message is "Expected byte, expression, label, or whitespace but " ' " found.

Comment: @Liuzili: I haven't used this simulator, I'm just reading the manual.  But it does say in the first paragraph that constants are decimal unless they are hex, so it may be that character constants are not fully supported.